# Python mechanize - form submission - selecting the correct form

Tags: python, web-scraping, mechanize

Trying to use Python mechanize to log in to a webpage. Since I have a problem with finding the correct form, instead of posting the URL (which the code might change) I will copy some of the code here for future users. I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8570920/submitting-forms-with-mechanize-python), but there didn't seem too be a definitive answer.

Anyways, I did everything with mechanize in [this tutorial](http://stockrt.github.com/p/emulating-a-browser-in-python-with-mechanize/) up until where I am getting the forms.

When I call:

```
for form in br.forms():
    print form
```

I get back:

```
POST https://www.myexample.com/x-www-form-urlencoded
HiddenControl(utf8=✓) (readonly)
HiddenControl(authenticity_token=BfqPL1ilOXeg08Or/CEBAiK4duWgncY=      
CheckboxControl(affiliate[remember_me]=[1])
```

Looking at the raw HTML I see:

```
<label for="affiliate_email">Email<./label>
<.input autofocus="autofocus" id="affiliate_email" 
    name="affiliate[email]" size="30" type="email" />
```

However, when I try to select the email field I get a form not found error.

```
br.select_form(name="affiliate[email]")
# updated to 
br.select_form(nr=0)
# Now what do I do here to enter something into that form?
br.form['someIDhere']='myEmail@example.com'
```

I have also tried using the form ID, and many other possible form names. I don't understand why printing the forms with br.forms() returns those strange results, does this mean the site is using javascript for login forms?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

`affiliate[email]` is not the name of a form, but of an input within the form.
Try using:

```
br.select_form(nr=0)
```

if the form has no name and is the first/only form on the page.

Comment: Right, I somehow managed to use the wrong syntax around the part I had a question about, I meant br.form[''] (after selecting the form I must input data into it). Updated my post. Thanks!